# Como hacer la igualdad de un campo id de mi tabla a otra en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo dos tablas

**Events**

```
ID_evt |   Numero   |   Orden   |   

1001   |      1     |     100    |     
1002   |      1     |     102    |    
1003   |      1     |     103    |    
1009   |      1     |     109    |     
1005   |      2     |     100    |    
1890   |      2     |     105    |  
1891   |      5     |     106    |  
1892   |      5     |     107    |  
1893   |      5     |     108    |
```

**Nombres**

```
CodNm   |   Titulo       |   Nombres   |

1001   |  SANTANA05X     |  SANTATJ    |
1001   |  JUANA07X       |  JUANXTJ    |
1001   |  FERNANDA01X    |  FERXMTJ    |
1002   |  SANTANA05X     |  SANTATJ    |
1002   |  JUANA07X       |  JUANXTJ    |
1004   |  R2D281X        |  R2D2MXN    |
1004   |  HAL023X        |  HALOMXN    |
1007   |  HAL026X        |  HALOMXN    |
1009   |  HXX029X        |  539        |
1009   |  FPX023X        |  544        |
1100   |  LHU029X        |  540        |
1100   |  POI025X        |  541        |
```

*con el siguiente query:*

```
SELECT  
   ideve.ID_evt,
   ideve.Orden,
   pik.CodNm
FROM 
    dataBaseTest01.Nombres pik 
JOIN    
    dataBaseTest01.Events ideve 
    
WHERE pik.CodNm = ideve.ID_evt
AND pik.Nombres in ('SANTATJ','JUANXTJ','FERXMTJ')
```

*El resultado que me da es el siguiente:*

> 

```
ID_evt |      Orden   |   Nombres   |

1001   |       100    |   SANTATJ   |
1001   |       100    |   JUANXTJ   |
1001   |       100    |   FERXMTJ   |
1002   |       102    |   SANTATJ   |
1002   |       102    |   JUANXTJ   |
```

Yo se que en la tabla Nombres, el campo Nombres el

> SANTATJ es el 539

, asi como el

> 544 es JUANXTJ

y el

> 541 = FERXMTJ

y asi como ese ejemplo tengo varios otros nombres que se relacionan,
como podria especificar eso en el query?

Para que quedara de la siguiente manera:

> 

```
ID_evt |      Orden   |   Nombres   |

1001   |       100    |   SANTATJ   |
1001   |       100    |   JUANXTJ   |
1001   |       100    |   FERXMTJ   |
1002   |       102    |   SANTATJ   |
1002   |       102    |   JUANXTJ   |
1009   |       109    |   539       |
1009   |       109    |   544       |
```

Comment: no es lo mas optimo, debes e separarlos por id y texto para que el campo nombres no contenga números, eso que estas haciendo, se puede pero seria una irresponsabilidad decirte como hacelo sin advertirte que es un serio problema de integridad de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes agregar otra condición en tus restricciones de filas o sea en el WHERE

tu sentencia quedaría así

```
     SELECT  
        ideve.ID_evt,
        ideve.Orden,
        pik.CodNm
     FROM 
        dataBaseTest01.Nombres pik 
     JOIN    
        dataBaseTest01.Events ideve 

      WHERE pik.CodNm = ideve.ID_evt
       AND (pik.Nombres in ('SANTATJ','JUANXTJ','FERXMTJ')) OR 
           (pik.Nombres in ('539','541','544'))
```